# How to post vertical photos on Instagram without cropping?

Tags: android, instagram, share

I have a image whose height width is equal to mobile screen height width. I want to post that image on Instagram without cropping by using Android native sharing. How can i make that image square programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram has specific limits to image sizes. You have to respect them, otherwise you have to crop your images.
Have you tried to resize the image?

Comment: Instagram post image size is 1080*1080px  but how can i resize my image without losing it's quality.